# Prove For all $x, y \in \Bbb R$. $x^{2}> y^{2} \Longleftrightarrow |x| >|y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am confused that whether taking square root on both sides of inequality preserves the inequality or not? If it does then how can we prove this using axioms of real numbers?

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused that whether taking square root on both sides of inequality preserves the inequality or not?

It does, because $\sqrt x$ is a monotone increasing function on the nonnegative reals. More generally, if $f$ is a monotone increasing function,

$$x > y \iff f(x) > f(y)$$

whenever $x,y$ are in the domain where $f$ is monotone increasing.

However, I personally prefer John P.'s method of factoring:

$$x^2 > y^2 \iff x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y) > 0 \implies |x| > |y|$$

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to my question. I have understood your point but just to be sure, can we say the same for all real numbers as well? I mean the proof you write, Is it applicable to non negative reals or for all reals x, y. ?

Comment: Yes, since regardless of whether $x$ is less than, equal to, or greater than zero, $x^2 \ge 0$ as is $|x|$. So everything works out fine.

Answer (score 1):

We have: 
\begin{align*}
x^2 = y^2 \iff x^2 - y^2 = 0 \iff (x+y)(x-y) = 0. 
\end{align*}
Hence, $x + y = 0$, in which case $x = -y$, or $x - y = 0$, in which case $x = y$. In either case, we have $|x| = |y|$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand your proof. Actually, we have been taught to prove this bidirectional in two steps . i.e. A ~ B can be proved by A imply B and then proving B imply A.

Comment: You could certainly do that. I'm taking it for granted that this is in fact a biconditional relationship, as is the case when we rearrange any equation. It isn't difficult to fill in the details.